# PHP If X greater than Y by more than Z

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to code a PHP `IF` statement:

```
If X is greater than Y by more than Z
```

Is this possible?

I can't find anything within 'Operators' [WS3 Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) nor within 'Else If' [PHP Else If](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) also tried a Google Search [php if x greater than y by more than z](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AVNA_enGB570GB571&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20if%20x%20greater%20than%20y%20by%20more%20than%20z)

Comment: Hint: use a subtraction

Comment: You mean if X > Y + Z ?

Comment: Oh crikeys....so....that'll be simply math then really huh!? DOH!  Thanks all.

Comment: somehow, *"jquery basic arithmetic plugin"* came to mind. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just try to do:

```
if (($X - $Y) > $Z) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
//it will full fill your first condtion that `$x has to be greater than $y`
// and second one is well that `$x-$y` has to be greater than $z.
if(($x-$y)>$z)
{
    echo 'hurray';
}
```

Comment: @Pogrindis i know apply this solution will work. with `if $x greater than $y` you dont have to type another line. This code will full fill all of your three condition.